# Is it possible to view a NEXT app hosted by one computer on another computer connected over same Wifi Network?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to view my NEXT APP from another computer. Both of them are connected over the same network.

IP of host network: XXX.XXX.X.X (obtained from `ipconfig` in windows machine under IpV4 address of LAN section)

On my Mac, I am using: http://XXX.XXX.X.X:3000/ but it says `This site can't be reached`. Like React application, is it possible to view the NEXT app onto another computer too or we can't do that here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next.js can start dev server with `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` with Host or IP configuration, just pass the flags into it with `-H`

```
yarn dev -H XXX.XXX.X.X
```

or

```
npm run dev -H XXX.XXX.X.X
```

then it will start the host or ip you pass instead of `0.0.0.0`

You can read the docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli)

Answer (score 1):

try to open the address with your phone connected to the wifi, if it's working there is a problem with your mac firewall.